# Does $\forall x (\phi(x) \vee \neg \phi(x))$ imply (2) $\forall x \phi (x) \vee \neg \forall x \phi(x)$ in intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

Does (1) $\forall x (\phi(x) \vee \neg \phi(x))$ imply (2) $\forall x \phi (x) \vee \neg \forall x \phi(x)$ in intuitionistic logic?

It seems to me that it does not, and my heuristic is this: (1) "says" that we have an algorithm that shows, for every object, that it is $\phi$ or not $\phi$. (2) "says" that either we have an algorithm that shows that every object is $\phi$, or we don't have it. (1) doesn't give us such an algorithm, nor does it show that there is no such thing, so it does not entail (2).

But, unless am I simply mistaken, the question is: how to show this more formally?

Comment: This is still intuitive but I agree with "no." Quantifying over even numbers greater than $2$, let $\phi$ be the statement that $x$ is the sum of two primes. Then (1) is true in intuitionistic logic (for all $x$ one either has a proof that $x$ is the sum of two primes or one has a proof that it is not, since one can exhaust), and (2) is false (one cannot exhibit a proof of Goldbach's conjecture or a counterexample).

Comment: Your statement on the meaning of the second clause in (2) is off. It doesn’t mean that we don’t have such an algorithm, it means that we have an algorithm that would take such an algorithm and produce from it a proof of $\bot.$

Comment: In a computability model of IL, a constructive proof of such an implication would give you something close to a solution to the halting problem: let $\phi(n)$ be the statement that a certain algorithm running on certain input does not halt after $n$ steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, the way to show that an implication does not hold is to give a countermodel.

This requires some notion of semantics. There are a few ways to give semantics to intuitionistic first-order logic, but the simplest is probably [Kripke semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Intuitionistic_first-order_logic).

It will suffice to find a countermodel to $\forall x\,(P(x)\lor \lnot P(x))\models \forall x\,P(x)\lor \lnot \forall x\, P(x)$, where $P$ is a unary relation symbol. That is, we want to find a Kripke model $M$ and a world $w$ in $M$ such that $w\models \forall x\,(P(x)\lor \lnot P(x))$ but $w\not\models \forall x\,P(x)\lor \lnot \forall x\, P(x)$.

The meaning of the first sentence is: for all worlds $w'\geq w$ and elements $x\in D(w')$, we have that $P$ holds of $x$, or for all worlds $w''\geq w'$, $P$ does not hold of $x$. Part of the definition of Kripke model is that if $P$ holds of $x$ in $w'$, then for all worlds $w''\geq w'$, $P$ holds of $x$. So $P$ cannot switch from "on" to "off", and this sentence says additionally that $P$ cannot switch from "off" to "on".  So intuitively, this says that the truth value of $P$ never switches.

The meaning of the second sentence is: Either it's true that for all $w'\geq w$ and  elements $x\in D(w')$, $P$ holds of $x$, or it's true that for all $w'\geq w$, there exists $w''\geq w'$ and an element $x\in D(w'')$ such that $P$ does not hold of $x$. Intuitively, either $P$ holds of everything in sight, or counterexamples to $P$ are "dense".

To get the second sentence to fail, we need:
(1) There exists $w'\geq w$ and $x\in D(w')$ such that $P$ does not hold of $x$, and  (2) there exists $w'\geq w$ such that for all $w''\geq w$ and all $x\in D(w'')$, $P$ holds of $x$.

Ok, now we can construct our countermodel. Let $W = \{w,w_1,w_2\}$ with $w\leq w_1$, $w\leq w_2$, and $w_1,w_2$ incomparable. Let $D(w) = D(w_2) = \{a\}$ and $D(w_1) = \{a,b\}$, with $P = \{a\}$ in all three worlds.

The truth value of $P$ never switches on an element, so $w\models \forall x\,(P(x)\lor \lnot P(x))$. The world $w_1\geq w$ witnesses condition (1), since $P$ does not hold of $b\in D(w_1)$, and the world $w_2\geq w$ witnesses condition (2), since $P$ holds of all elements of all worlds $\geq w_2$. So $w\not\models \forall x\,P(x)\lor \lnot \forall x\, P(x)$.